# cakephp set console path

Tags: shell, cakephp, cron

i wish to send bulk email through cron job in cakephp 2.0 through theu se of cakephp shell console script. For that i need to set PATH in .bashrc in linux.
i referred http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html
I wrote `export PATH="$PATH:/directory_name/web/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console"` as said in the link in .bashrc. when i write cake in console it says:

```
The program 'cake' is currently not installed.  To run 'cake' please ask your administrator to install the package 'cakephp-scripts'
```

Where am i getting wrong? How do i get started with this?

Comment: So, "cakephp-scripts" is installed or not?

Comment: is there a way to access cakephp shell without installing cakephp-scripts package? Sorry but i am a complete noob to this, hence such a question

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute path to run Cake's Console:

```
$ /directory_name/web/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/cake
```